# Custom multiline UILabel with black background behind text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I need to create custom multiline UILabel with black background behind text, with some pading of 2 pixel from left, right, top and bottom. Padding must be same for all side, let say if padding between [Songs.. and black border = 2 then I need 2pixel padding between "Perfect" and right border, same after "mp3"

I tried this:

```
[string addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
          value:[UIColor blackColor]
          range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```

but its not giving me extra padding.

[image: Example image]

Could you guys suggest me any library or some hint will also be helpful

Comment: What about adding spaces?

Comment: I am able to add space before [Songs and after mp3 but its not possible after Perfect.

Challeging part is to set pading after text Perfect.

Comment: @ZoebS why don't you just use a UITextView?

Comment: @AlexanderMacLeod do you think UITextView solve my problem? what are the advantages of using UITextView over UIlabel in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `UITextView` rather than a `UILabel`. Do something like the following:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, 40)];
textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```